# Value of $( \lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\lim _{x\to 1}\left(x^n\right)\right) )$

Tags: calculus, limits

What is the value of $ \lim\limits _{n\to \infty }\left(\lim\limits_{x\to 1}\left(x^n\right)\right) $, or does it it have no finite value?

I was originally thinking that the value of the inner limit is 1, and so the outer limit becomes $ 1^{\to \infty } $ which is 1. However I doubt that is correct as I don't think the inner limit will be a perfect 1.

Comment: limits, if they exist, are always perfect (so the answer is $1$).

Comment: Your thoughts are correct. Sometimes there are complex questions about changing the order of taking limits, and some weird things can happen. This is not one of those times :)

Comment: Aside: `\lim` already comes with an implicit limits specification; you can just write `\lim_{n \to \infty}` to get the desired formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parentheses still enforce order of operations, even when limits, derivatives, integrals, series, or the like are involved.

Thus, $\lim_{x \to 1} (x^n)$ is computed *before* anything related to the outer limit, and you can substitute in its value, so that

$$\lim\limits _{n\to \infty }\left(\lim\limits_{x\to 1}\left(x^n\right)\right) = \lim\limits _{n\to \infty }\left(1\right) = 1$$

(Aside: be wary of settings where the actual operation being performed is not what it looks like! Physics is notorious for this, often doing calculus with *distributions* rather than functions, but using the same notation as calculus with functions. Because of how distributions work, the end result often looks like operations are being performed in the opposite order than the formula indicates!)

Comment: could you please give a simple sample of this distribution/orderchanging thing ?

Comment: @magma: A common place it comes up (and matters) is when the dirac delta is involved. For example, if you take a sequence $s_n(x)$ that a physicist would say converges to the dirac delta, you can see that (for nice functions), $\int \left( \lim_{n \to \infty} s_n(x) \right) f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$ is zero, so it sounds like the physicist is talking nonsense, but if we interpret the limit as one of distributions rather than functions, it is instead equal to $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int s_n(x) f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = f(0)$ (where *this* limit is a limit of numbers), which agrees with the physicist.

Answer (score 7):

$ \lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\lim _{x\to 1}\left(x^n\right)\right) =\lim _{n\to \infty }1=1$